# FTP Client/Server with Web Based UI/API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, user-interface, ftp, jruby

I don't even know where to begin to look for something like this, or whether or not one even exists. What I am generally looking for is a FTP Server that I can run in the background of any given linux distro. Particularly RedHat and Ubuntu. Having this server run as a service on the machine. Then through that I need a FTP client that can interact with that particular service thats built into a Browser based UI. It would be nice to have something that I can tie the server admin into the UI as well.

So my question here is, is there anything like that, that anyone knows of? The UI portion should be able to support (j)Ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F->It may fit the bill.  It has a Javascript client wrapped in Rails on the server.

Read about it:
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/web-based-ftp-client-similar-to-windows-explorer/

See a demo:
https://fit.jupiterit.com/

Download it:
http://code.google.com/p/f-it/